# how to initialize a QString to null?

Tags: c++, qstring

What is the difference between `QString::number(0)` and `((const char*) 0)`?

I want to initialize a `QString` say `phoneNumber` to `null`. Will `phoneNumber(QString::number(0))` and `phoneNumber((const char*) 0)` both work?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To create a null `QString` just default initialize it:

```
QString phoneNumber;

// or if you already have a QString variable and want to 'clear' it:

phoneNumber = QString();
```

Note that `QString::number(0)` is decidedly *not* null - it creates a QString with the value `"0"`.

You could also initialize the `QString` with a `NULL` pointer, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you're passing a pointer regardless of whether it's `NULL` or not (i.e., it could sometimes point to a C string) since it's unnecessary.

You should also understand the [following Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#distinction-between-null-and-empty-strings):

> Distinction Between Null and Empty Strings
>
> For historical reasons, `QString` distinguishes between a null string
>   and an empty string. A null string is a string that is initialized
>   using `QString`'s default constructor or by passing `(const char *)0`
>   to the constructor. An empty string is any string with size 0. A null
>   string is always empty, but an empty string isn't necessarily null:
>
> ```
> QString().isNull();               // returns true
> QString().isEmpty();              // returns true
>
> QString("").isNull();             // returns false
> QString("").isEmpty();            // returns true
>
> QString("abc").isNull();          // returns false
> QString("abc").isEmpty();         // returns false
> ```
>
> All functions except `isNull()` treat null strings the same as empty
>   strings. For example, `toAscii().constData()` returns a pointer to a
>   `'\0'` character for a null string (not a null pointer), and
>   `QString()` compares equal to `QString("")`. We recommend that you
>   always use the `isEmpty()` function and avoid `isNull()`.

Comment: Michael thanks for your response, but one thing is unclear to me - does str.clear() leaves empty string or nullified one. If empty is there a way to nullify it?

Comment: `QString::clear()` sets the string to null (i.e., after `str.clear()`, str.isNull() will return `true`).

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString name(QString::null);
    // or QString name = QString::null;
    // or QString name;

    qDebug() << name.isNull();
    qDebug() << name;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
true
""
```

Michael Burr`s solution is of course also correct... But I like the `QString::null` more.

Comment: Thumbs up for explicitly including QString::null. I like the way it eliminates any/all ambiguity in intention.

Comment: @RobertOliveira Agreed! Had no idea about this until just now.

Comment: @rob One downside of using `QString::null` is that, on Windows, it will cause a data symbol to be imported - which in turn prohibits [delay-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/delayload-delay-load-import?view=vs-2019) the Qt (resp. Qt Core) library.

Comment: Qt Creator now announces that `QString::null` is deprecated. It recommends the usage of `String()` instead.

Comment: @RonanPaixão could you give us a short example? I'm struggling with that as well.

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn see the accepted answer for details. In essence, you just use the default initializer. Simply this should work: `QString phoneNumber;`.

Comment: @RonanPaixão ah, I get you! I see; but my problem is actually that I'm refactoring old code which has some default values on a class method — one of which being a `QString`! I wonder, how should I deal with that? (my workaround: for the moment, ignore the default value and cross my fingers and hope it'll work... somehow!)