# QStrings isNull out of QSettings is wrong

Tags: c++, qt

I notice that QSettings is not able to store the isNull property of a QString. In other cases (QTime) the QSettings works as expected. Do I something wrong?

```
#include <QTime>
#include <QString>
#include <QSettings>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString str;
    QTime time;
    std::cout << "String is null: " << std::boolalpha << str.isNull() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time is null: " << std::boolalpha << time.isNull() << std::endl;
    QSettings settings("Settings");
    settings.setValue("string", str);
    settings.setValue("time", time);
    std::cout << "String is null: " << std::boolalpha << settings.value("string").toString().isNull() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time is null: " << std::boolalpha << settings.value("time").toTime().isNull() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
String is null: true
Time is null: true
String is null: false
Time is null: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note from the documentation: "Qt makes a distinction between null strings and empty strings for historical reasons." I would assume it is better not to rely on this distinction. Instead of setting a null string you would be better off to not set the option at all (or explicitely unset it).

The practical reason for QSettings not being able to store null string is most probably that the storage format simply does not support this. One common format to store settings is the INI format (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#Format-enum)) which is unable to provide a distinction between empty and null.

Apart from that, I would use [QVariant::isNull()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#isNull) instead of converting to string.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice the ini is not able to distingish between empty and Null.

Answer (score 0):

Try type `settings.value("string").isNull()` instead of `settings.value("string").toString().isNull()`.
Because you try cast to String type null-value.

I've used this ([how to initialize a QString to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724966/how-to-initialize-a-qstring-to-null)) post for answer to you

Comment: The variant is in this case also not Null.